# html to dynamicly list files in a directory

Tags: html, website

I am in the process of redoing some of our company website. We do a lot of recruiting and so we change job descriptions on our job offering page quiet often.

I was wondering what is the best way to have some sort of dynamic table of contents so that if I add an additional job description that I don't have to edit the TOC.

Here is what it looks like currently
http://www.markonsolutions.com/opportunities.html

which is the style I like but If I add/remove a page I have to edit this page.
Is there anyway that I can make the web page just see everything in a folder and list it there?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a scripting language like [PHP to read the files](http://www.laughing-buddha.net/jon/php/dirlist/) in the directory. Personally I would do something like this:

1. Create a PDF file for each job description (i.e. design-manager.pdf , financial-manager.pdf)
2. Use PHP to loop through the directory, and add the file name to an array
3. Manipulate the array to output the HTML (remove the dash using [str_replace](http://us.php.net/str_replace) and capitalize the job title using [ucwords](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php)).

Answer (score 3):

html can't do this. Use CGI or look into a scripting language such as PHP, perl, asp, etc.

Comment: HTML is a static language. For dynamic content your best choices are either PHP or JSP (JavaServer Pages).

Comment: @NoCanDo: Aren't Python, Ruby, .NET, pretty much anything else more available than JSP these days?